# Extending LVM partition on Debian/Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, debian, lvm

I've just resized the Virtual Space on VirtualBox image 5G to 15G. I then used GParted to resize the physical partition which now looks like this:

[image]

and using fdisk command:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 16.1 GB, 16106127360 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1958 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009221c

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          32      248832   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              32        1959    15477761    5  Extended
/dev/sda5              32         689     5280768   8e  Linux LVM
```

The problem is I can't find any examples for resizing the LVM partition that look similar to this or on Debian.

Most examples look something like this but I'm not exactly sure

```
pvresize /dev/sda5
pvscan
lvextend -L +10G /dev/? /dev/sda5
resize2fs /dev/?/lv_root
```

**Update**

So I figured out the correct command is:

```
lvextend -L +10G /dev/private2/root
```

Which gives now gives error message:

```
Extending logical volume root to 14.78 GiB
Insufficient free space: 2560 extents needed, but only 0 available
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/private2/root
```

This command should work for you.